# How many basic operations in this line?

Tags: operation

How many basic operations in the line:

```
int a = b++;
```

Since b is being incremented by one AND being stored in int a, does that mean there's 2? I just want to make sure because at first I've always considered this to be just one operation.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two operations, but first operation is `=`, where value of `b`is assigned to `a` and next is increment `++`. As you can see it is postincrement and incrementation is side-efect. On the other hand, if it vas preincrement, `int a = ++b`, first operation would be increment and second assigning that incremented value of `b` to `a`.